# My Keepass file .kdbx is impossible to open or repair because of corrupted header

Tags: passwords, keepass

I am tying to use Keepass in order to open a .kdbx file.
Every time I try I have this message:
"Failed to load the specified file !
The filie signature is invalid. Either the file isn't a KeePass database file at all or it is corrupted".

I already try to create another identical .kdbx file but it continues to happen.
I also try to repair my file with the KeePass KDBX (2x) Repar Mode, it's still corrupted.

My version of keepass is KeePass-2.54, and my file was create on visual Studio code.

Thank you all for your help.

[image]

Comment: Try to use https://keepass.info/help/base/repair.html